# SQL WITH RECURSIVE as subselect?

Tags: sql, postgresql, common-table-expression

I have two tables:

- stay(uid, building_unit_uid)
- building_unit(uid, building_unit_uid, type)

building_unit_uid is the building_unit the current building_unit belongs to, i.e. the one is a room and points to a floor. The floor would point to a building.

The stay would point to a room.

I need to get the building for every stay.

I managed to use WITH RECURSIVE manually to find the building for a given building_unit:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gQnYbShBaDqxa6rQBQtTRG/1

```
create table stay(uid int, building_unit_uid int);
create table building_unit(uid int, building_unit_uid int, type int);
insert into building_unit (uid, building_unit_uid, type) values (1, null, 1), (2, 1, 2), (3, 1, 2), (4, 2, 3), (5, 2, 3), (6, 3, 3), (7, 3, 3);
insert into stay (uid, building_unit_uid) values (1, 6), (2, 7);

WITH RECURSIVE building(uid, building_unit_uid, type) AS (
  SELECT building_unit.uid, building_unit.building_unit_uid, building_unit.type
  FROM building_unit
  WHERE building_unit.uid = 7
  UNION
  SELECT b.uid, b.building_unit_uid, b.type
  FROM building_unit AS b
  INNER JOIN building AS bu ON bu.building_unit_uid = b.uid
  )
  SELECT * FROM building WHERE type = 1
```

What I need is a stay query with a joined building uid for it's building_unit_uid. I have no idea how I can use the WITH RECURSIVE query as a subquery for a stay query or if I could join them or whatever.

The desired output would be:

```
uid building_unit_uid parent_building_unit_uid
1   6                 1
2   7                 1
```

Comment: What is a "stay" query?

Comment: select * from stay for instance. I mentioned that I have a stay table.

Comment: Definitely not clear what "Stay" should be.
When I need to use recursion, specially with deep depth, I use a hierarchyid Field, it make your life so much better.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/hierarchyid-data-type-method-reference, if your current database don't have it, you can simulate the string representation

Comment: Stay is just a table, where every entry points to a building_unit. Did you look at the fiddle?

Comment: Add your desired output to your question, that should help clear things up.

Comment: Are you saying that you store building IDs in rows with `type = 1`, floors of a building in rows with `type = 2`, and actual rentable units on a floor of a building in rows with `type = 3`, and given an arbitrary rentable unit ID, you need to find the building ID that contains that unit?  If so, I think you've made your schema unsensibly complicated — it certainly isn't the way I'd organize it.  However, if you have just a 3-level hierarchy, you can do two inner self-joins to get the result.  If the hierarchy can be deeper than that (more than building, floor, unit), then say so.

Comment: You are right, I would have organized it differently, but I have to work with what I got. Yes, the 3-level organization is just an example, you can have beds in rooms to start with or not only floors but actual building parts so the hierarchy can vary. It even hasn't be the same for two entry points (rooms in the example here).